# Can't import Reveal.js with Webpack 2.2

Tags: javascript, webpack, reveal.js

I'm trying to import reveal.js with webpack 2.2 using the imports-loader but I keep getting an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Reveal' of undefined

I'm trying to import it like this:
`require('imports-loader?this=>window!reveal.js');`

That should inject the global window variable as `this`.

The part of code causing the error is this:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (true) {

        root.Reveal = factory();
    }
})(undefined, function () {
```

`undefined` on the last line is being passed into  the function as the `root` parameter.

This code is how webpack is importing the reveal.js library. For some reason it seems like webpack is replacing the word `this` with `undefined` when it bundles the code together.

How can I properly import this library with webpack? I've also tried script-loader and I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webpack configuration:

```
rules: [
  { parser: { amd: false }}
]
```

This will prevent webpack from defining AMD define variable, which is why reveal.js is triggering that condition in its factory wrapper.

After that I also am importing reveal.js and head.js via

```
import head from 'headjs/dist/1.0.0/head';
import Reveal from 'reveal.js/js/reveal';

// Reveal.initialize(
```